# Winston logging - pretty JSON format in Winston 3.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, console.log, winston

I was working with Winston few years ago. When we were developing on localhost our winston was configured to output nice formatted JSON which was easy to read.

**2.x Winston**

`npm install winston@2.2.0`

```
const winston = require('winston');
const logger = new winston.Logger({
    transports: [new (winston.transports.Console)({ json: true })],
});

logger.info('please', { iam: 'good' });
try {
    throw new Error('ooh noo');
} catch (err) {
    logger.error('Not good error', err);
}
```

has this output

```
{
  "iam": "good",
  "level": "info",
  "message": "please"
}
{
  "message": "Not good error",
  "stack": "Error: ooh noo\n    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\libor\\WebstormProjects\\untitled\\usewinston.js:30:11)\n    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/
modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)\n    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)\n    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)\n    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_
main.js:72:12)\n    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47",
  "level": "error"
}
```

**3.x Winston**

`npm install winston` (newest version or 3.3.3 when writing this article)

```
const winston = require('winston');

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
    format: winston.format.json(),
});


logger.add(new winston.transports.Console({
    format: winston.format.json(),
}));

logger.info('please', { iam: 'good' });
try {
    throw new Error('ooh noo');
} catch (err) {
    logger.error('Not good error', err);
}
```

has this output

```
{"iam":"good","level":"info","message":"please"}
{"level":"error","message":"Not good error ooh noo","stack":"Error: ooh noo\n    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\libor\\WebstormProjects\\untitled\\usewinston.js:21:11)\n    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)\n    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)\n    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)\n    at Function.executeU
serEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)\n    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"}
```

**Question**

Is there some native/easy way to get same output like I had in 2.x version in newest (3.3.3) version? If not, do you know the best way to achieve it?

**Bonus question**

The Webstorm is not able to detect (in neither of above examples) the files and lines in stacktrace, therefore its not clickable.
When I just "console.error" the stack trace looks like this:

[image: webstorm]

and I can directly click the file to navigate to it in the line that caused error.
Do you know how to achieve it in Winston 3.x?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it with custom formatter as following

```
const winston = require('winston');
const _ = require('lodash');

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    level: 'info',
});

const logStackAndOmitIt = winston.format((info, opts) => {
    if (info.stack){
        console.error(info.stack);
        return _.omit(info, 'stack');
    }
    return info;
});

logger.add(new winston.transports.Console({
        format: winston.format.combine(
            logStackAndOmitIt(),
            winston.format.prettyPrint(),
        ),
    })
);

const arr = Array(50).fill(20)

logger.info('pleases', { iam: 'abc', arr });
try {
    throw new Error('ooh noo');
} catch (err) {
    logger.error('Not good error', err);
}
```

Which has this output

```
{
  iam: 'abc',
  arr: [
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20,
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20,
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20,
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20,
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20
  ],
  level: 'info',
  message: 'pleases'
}
Error: ooh noo
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\libor\WebstormProjects\untitled\usewinston.js:71:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
{ level: 'error', message: 'Not good error ooh noo' }
```

Including clickable link in Webstorm